Initializiation of full properties on non-nullable-references
In nullable-enabled code, when defining a full qualified property, like
public class C1
{
    private string _value;

    public string Value { get => _value; set => _value = value; }

    public C1()
    {
        Value = "Test";
    }
}

I get
"CS8618 Non-nullable field '_value' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor."
When I convert it to an auto-property, the problem is solved.
Is there any way to tell the compiler Value is set through _value ?
A nicer way then #pragma disable ....
I tried
 [MemberNotNull((nameof(_value)))]
 public C1()
 {
     Value = "Test";
 }

but that's not allowed on constructors eithers.

You should put [MemberNotNull((nameof(_value)))] in the setter of Value.

Thanks, you should upgrade this to an answer.
